# Zabbix REST-API output limited to 100k records

Tags: php, rest, monitoring, zabbix

I'm trying to get the history records for an item via Zabbix REST-API, it seems like the API can only return up to 100k records.

My goal is to get the historical data about the availability per host, the service (Ping Host) is executed each minute so there are more than 500k records.

My API call params are as following:

```
    $all_params = array(
            "history"       => "3",
    #       'limit'         => "100000",
            'output'        =>  "extend",
            'filter'        => array('X' => '10177','itemid' => 'Y'),
    );

    $allinfo = $api->historyGet($all_params);
    $all_data = json_decode(json_encode($allinfo), True);
```

In case I set the limit to 100k, the API returns last 100k records, in case I comment that parameter out ( so I want all the records) it actually doesn't return anything, not even an empty string. It seems like the API call timed-out. I know that Zabbix is storing "trend" data in the DB, unfortunately, that's not useful for me because it only stores the minx,max,ave values, and that's too inaccurate for my purposes.

I call the API and process the data in PHP script.

Does anyone know how to change this limit from 100k to something else? IT might be related to a configuration of some buffer.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure its the api and not your script running out of memory? `json_decode(json_encode())`? also expecting a web service to supply all the data every min, is overreaching and really inefficient, cant you reconcile the data, then use paging or not return so much and just keep on top of it.

Comment: You should check your webserver's error_log, I think that you will find a HTTP 500 Internal server error. As @LawrenceCherone pointed out, it's probably an out of memory issue.